# How to make request over https proxy in request/node-fetch module in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, request, fetch

I am trying make http(s) request over only https proxy server. But i am getting this error:

```
: FetchError: request to https://google.com/ failed, reason: write EPROTO 17272:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332
```

My code:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

fetch('https://google.com', {
  agent:new HttpsProxyAgent('https://username@password@host:8000'),
}).then(async (res) => {
  console.log(await res.text());
})
```

If i made it with `request` module and disabled `pool` option, it will be ok:

```js
const request = require('request');

request({
  url: 'https://google.com',
  proxy: 'https://username@password@host:8000',
  pool: false //ONLY IF THIS false
}, (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res); // OK
})
```

If i made this with `http` proxy protocol, it will be ok too.

So, how can i fix it? I need support `https` proxy in my program, but i don't know how to make it. The request module is deprecated, i use node-fetch in product

Comment: What version of Node.js are you running?  It might need an update if it's very old.  SSLv3 should have been disabled years ago.

Comment: Using node.js 14